# Python - Read Mp4 to Bits

Tags: python, encryption, io, byte

I'm working on a coursera cryptography project.  It requires taking an MP4 file, and reading it into 1KB chunks in bits.  I have some code which does this, more or less.  Posted below.  But how can I do this without manually adding the padding? How can I just read this directly into bits as its stored in the MP4?

```
import binascii

file = open("tagthis.mp4", "rb")
allbytes = []
while 1:
  somebytes = file.read(1024)

  if not somebytes:
    break

  chunk = ""
  for byte in somebytes:
    byte =  bin(ord(byte))
    byte = byte[2:len(byte)]
    padding = "0" * (8 - len(byte))
    chunk += padding + byte

  allbytes.append(chunk)
```

Comment: Why do you need to add padding at all?

Comment: Well what if I have the values 2 & 3 in bits.  Without padding it would look like 1011, and with padding it would look like 0000001000000011.  In the first case tha now looks like the number 11 to me.

Comment: I see. So what are the cases where it doesn't work? It looks like an ok way to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Its slow.  And (i think) overly complicated

Comment: As far as I know, the Mp4 is stored in binary.  So it doesnt make sense for me to read it into ascii, and then convert it back into binary.  It seems there should be a way to read it directly into binary the way its stored.

Comment: Yes, file data is stored in binary, but what you want is not binary, but a binary representation. The smallest unit that can be read is a byte in most (all?) languages. You can't read a single bit from a file or from somewhere else for that matter. You can access single bits after reading a byte by doing some bit operations like shifting and such. It's fine to let python do a part of the conversion from a byte to a binary representation of that byte.

Comment: You are confused about what's happening. You aren't reading it in ascii then converting "back" to binary, you are reading it in binary, the way it's stored. Then you are converting it into an ascii representation to make it more human readable. An ASCII character is itself a byte. You are converting a byte into a string of eight ASCII characters.